# How to overcome this issue: Function is not defined in python.?

Tags: python

Good day I have the following snippet:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#! /usr/bin/python3

from sys import version_info
import logging

py3 = version_info[0] > 2 

if py3:
    name = input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)
else:
    name = raw_input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)


def verify_user(name):
    if name is not 'My Admin':
        logging.warning('What the hell are you doing in here ???')
    else:
        logging.info('Welcome Dear Admin')
```

When I run it through the shell doing: ./log.py, I'm receiving the following error:

```
verify_user is not define.
```

Not sure what is going on. I have defined the verify_user().
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Python is an interpreted, dynamic programming language. Define before calling a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a [**dynamic** language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language), hence you need to 1st define the function and then use it.

Solution: Put the whole function definition before using it.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#! /usr/bin/python3

from sys import version_info
import logging

def verify_user(name):
    if name is not 'My Admin':
        logging.warning('What the hell are you doing in here ???')
    else:
        logging.info('Welcome Dear Admin')

py3 = version_info[0] > 2 

if py3:
    name = input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)
else:
    name = raw_input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)
```

Comment: @ritesht93, when I run this snippet no matter what my keyboard input is, it's just showing the logging.warning(), while what I want is when the name input equals My Admin, to display the else part.

Comment: @thePhenom use `!=` instead of `is not`

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `verify_user` before you define it. Move the `verify_user` function  to the top of your file.

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
#! /usr/bin/python3

from sys import version_info
import logging

def verify_user(name):
    if name is not 'My Admin':
        logging.warning('What the hell are you doing in here ???')
    else:
        logging.info('Welcome Dear Admin')

py3 = version_info[0] > 2 

if py3:
    name = input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)
else:
    name = raw_input('What is your name?: ')
    verify_user(name)
```

Comment: when I run this snippet no matter what my keyboard input is, it's just showing the logging.warning(), while what I want is when the name input equals My Admin, to display the else part.